# Break function on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
li.click(function () {
    div = 0;

    $(this).children('label').children('div').on('click', function () {
        return div = 1;
    });
    console.log(div);
    if (div === 1) {
        console.log(123);
        return;
    }
```

I want to exit from function, when "div" is clicked, but div variable always is 0. How to change this?

Comment: Suggest you to include your HTML also.

Comment: Yeh when what div is clicked?

Comment: The function `.on()` returns immediately. The closure passed as an argument is not called until the click event occurs.

Comment: Your event listeners are not bound properly. You need to separate the `li` click listener and `div` click listener. Your `div` click listener is never called thats why your div variable is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should enable your behavior of setting the `variable div` to 1 when the `div` inside the `label` inside the `li` inside the `ul` would be clicked and driving special behavior on that value being 1 or not.  Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9pxgdpgz/

Javascript:

```
var div = 0;

$("li").on("click", function () {
    if (div === 1){
        alert("div is 1");
        div = 0;
        console.log(123);

        return;
    } else {
        alert("div is not 1");   
    }
    // Do more stuff here if not 1?
});

$("li").children("label").children("div").on("click", function () {
    // Set global variable to 1.
    div = 1;
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    LI IS HERE<br />
    <label>
        LABEL IS HERE<br />
        <div>
            DIV IS HERE
        </div>
    </label>
</li>
</ul>
```